# How to find the java files associated with the .cache.html file

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I have to debug something for a school project, and I am wondering where is it declared which Java files are to be used for the `.cache.html` file. Does this exists in a pom file? 
I know they use maven to build their projects.

Comment: The .cache and .nocache files are generated by GWT compiler. User is not supposet to debug into these files. If you post some detail on what you are trying to debug, then I might be able to help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to figure out the java code from the compiled output.

Well, that is not entirely true because when you are developing, in the debug flow, you can use superdev-mode which maintains a set of source-maps so as Chrome browsers (or other source-map featured browser in the future) can inspect java sources.

But in you case, you have to ask for the original project sources, open it in your favourite java IDE, run devmode and debug it as a normal java application, run super-devmode and debug in chrome, or compile the project as PRETTY and debug with normal javascript tools.

Note that devmode is being deprecated because of plugin development constrains in modern versions of FF and Chrome.